# Employee Availability in Microsoft Form

Tags: forms, microsoft365

I'm currently making an employee availability and skill selection form. I'm beginning with a Microsoft Form where the employee can select their skills from a premade list, how many hours a week they can work, etc.

I, however, also want a section where the employee can enter in their availability like this:

> Monday: 9:00 AM - 5:00 PM
>
> Tuesday: 9:00 AM - 5:00 PM

Is there a way to do this in Microsoft Form, or perhaps a better tool for what I'm going for?